# How to make multilevel height stretch in browser?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need controlling height layout which is close to desktop behavior:

1. I set top level height of dom element.
2. Deep inside it content automatically scales for new height.

For one level of hierarchy it is easy to implement with flex. But I need layout like that:

```
<top height="...rem">
  <header height="...rem"/>
  <main> // stretched height
    <main2> // stretched height
      <content>
        limited height by main2 and add scroll if necessary
      </content>
    </main2>
    <footer height="...rem"/>
  </main>
</top>
```

I made proof-of-concept which solve this problem with flex and absolute position of content.

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfgq93h/6/

So questions:

1. Is it possible to implement it simpler?
2. What are pitfalls of proof-of-concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one problem is that there doesn't seem to be any need for the `<main2>` element or the `.submain` class as you called it in the fiddle.

The main thing to note is that you want some of the flex elements (I'm specifically talking about the children of a parent with `display: flex`) to have a fixed size (e.g. header and footer) and some to have variable size. For this you can use a combination of `flex: none` and `flex: 1 1`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.height-limit {
  height: 10rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  flex: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #bdc3c7;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #e74c3c;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #3498db;
}

footer {
  flex: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<div class="height-limit">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body some body  
    </div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```